# Redux form not updated for new material-ui i.e. "@material-ui/core": "^3.3.2"

Tags: redux-form

`"material-ui/core": "^3.3.2"` is very different compared to  `"material-us": "^0.19.2"`. The examples in redux forms are not working for `material-ui`.

Answer (score 0):

Someone updated this just as you were posting about it. PRs always welcome.